# Thought process of CASE syntax in SQL

Tags: sql, case, case-when

I have the following code (I'm using northwind database) which give me the result shown in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFGMp.png)

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.TitleOfCourtesy, a.Notes, c.CustomerYear
FROM employees a
    INNER JOIN orders b
    ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE a.TitleOfCourtesy = 'Ms.';
```

The code above combines three tables and selecting only rows with `a.TitleOfCourtesy = 'Ms.'`

From the result I want to take the rows that has `%1992%` in the column `a.Notes` and only show rows that has the `c.CustomerYear` equal to 1992. So in the picture earlier I should only get the second top row visible.

I thought I could use the CASE + WHEN syntax to create a kind of IF statement but I only get invalid use of syntax at the CASE line. Should the CASE part be moved after the WHERE part or do I use it completely wrong?

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.TitleOfCourtesy, a.Notes, c.CustomerYear

CASE 
    WHEN a.Notes LIKE '%1992%' THEN c.CustomerYear LIKE '1992' 
    ELSE NULL END 

FROM employees a
    INNER JOIN orders b
    ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE a.TitleOfCourtesy = 'Ms.';
```

How should I think to achieve my desired result?

Comment: `CASE` is for varying a value depending on the row, but does not filter the rows. `WHERE` is for filtering rows.

Comment: As I'm trying to learn, do you mind to give a short example about what you mean: _varying a value depending_ . It would be much appreciated!!

Comment: `select case when score > 80 then 'A' when score between 70 and 79 then 'B' else 'Pass' end as grade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to expand the `WHERE` clause...

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.TitleOfCourtesy, a.Notes, c.CustomerYear
FROM employees a
    INNER JOIN orders b
    ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE a.TitleOfCourtesy = 'Ms.'
  AND a.Notes LIKE '%1992%'
  AND c.CustomerYear LIKE '1992';
```

I also only see ***one*** matching row in your image, not two.  So I may have misunderstood what you want to achieve...  Maybe you want this to get two rows?

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.TitleOfCourtesy, a.Notes, c.CustomerYear
FROM employees a
    INNER JOIN orders b
    ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON b.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE a.TitleOfCourtesy = 'Ms.'
  AND a.Notes LIKE '%1992%'
  AND (c.CustomerYear LIKE '1992' OR c.CustomerYear IS NULL)
```

Finally, you don't need `LIKE '1992'` you can just use `= '1992'`, and if the value is a integer just use `= 1992`...

Comment: Yes it worked, now I only need to understand why I didn't need to use the CASE syntax, as I thought it was used to create conditions... 
Or is this only a filter issue that I had and not an evaluate problem?

Comment: I was not clear enough. Your first code was what I was looking for. It should only be one row visible (the 2nd row from the top) as it contains the value `1992` in both the column `a.Notes` and `c.CustomerYear`

Comment: @LindaStenn `CASE` is effectively `SWITCH`.  It takes scalar values and returns one scalar result.  Like an inline `IF`?  `CASE number % 2 WHEN 0 THEN 'even' WHEN 1 THEN 'odd' ELSE 'NULL' END` takes a number and returns one of three possible strings...

Comment: @mat `ELSE NULL` is redundant it’s implied if no cases match

Comment: @Bohemian Except that I didn't write `ELSE NULL`, I wrote `ELSE 'NULL'` to return a string not a NULL value.